# Subscription responses sent multiple times

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When working with an event that I am subscribed to, I receive 4 separate JSON responses, all of the same JSON format described in here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0

The only difference in these responses is the changeType.  When creating an event, I get a response with changeType "created", and the other 3 responses are changeType "updated".  What is the purpose/reasoning for the multiple responses with the same data?

Comment: There isn't a lot of detail here. How was the event created? Is this a meeting with multiple attendees? A recurring event?